# Best Way To Parse A WSDL File In JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

am Looking For the Best Way To Parse **WSDL** File using JavaScript , am developing a small application to generate code for a web Service after the user uploads a wsdl file .

So what is the Best Way to implement that , i have no experience in this field ?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [wsdj2j](https://npmjs.org/package/wsdl2.js) module to consume a WSDL file and generate Javascript library

First, you need to consume your WSDL and generate appropriate JS:

```
wsdl2.js [serviceName] [/local/path/to/wsdl]
```

Then prepare the request:

```
var Service = require("path/to/generated/code");
var EC2 = require("lib/EC2");
This is how we create a new request:
var someRequest = new Service.[WSDL-Binding-Name].[WSDL-Operation-Name]();
var json = { someNumber: 1, someString: "1" };
someRequest = new Service.TestRequest(json);
// someRequest.someNumber == 1
// someRequest.someString == "1"
```

Executing the request:

```
someRequest.request(function(err, response) {
  // 'response' is a modeled object, it WILL conform to the WSDL.
  //... w00p!
});
```

Comment: But am making the user upload a file , so i need to generate the appropriate JS from wsdl using the application it self , so i when a user uploads a wsdl the js will be generated.

Comment: If your app has to generate JS by itself, you only need to parse WSDL file - it's just regular XML file, so any XML parser will do. Module mentioned above could play a role of example in your endeavor